# how to permanently set sublimelinter css rules on sublimetext 3?

Tags: css, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I'm trying to find a way to permanently set sublimelinter css rules on sublimetext 3, but I can't find.. How to? :)

I'm not too good with the terminal. I also tried to put a .csslintrc on my home dir but it doesn't work. It's not like jshint.

Comment: I think I could import in my scss files a global .scss with inline rules like these /*csslint errors:true, duplicate-properties:true, known-properties:true, ids:false*/ etc.. but I don't like this way

Comment: ok no, csslint doesn't apply to scss files

Comment: What SublimeLinter plugin are you using for CSS? Have you read its documentation for configuring it?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a .csslintrc file in the CSS folder, not in the project root, (and duplicate it for each sub folder...)

```
--ignore=ids
```

Otherwise, you can add a **.sublimelinterrc** config file at your home dir.

```
{
    "linters": {
        "csslint": {
          "ignore": ["ids"]
        }
      }
}
```